# NoMethodError: undefined method `params' - during controller tests with Authlogic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, authlogic

I have one controller method which I'd like to test. I have a case which requires user to be logged in. I use Authlogic for that purpose, so I wrote my test that way:

```
test "should get edit" do
  Authlogic::Session::Base.controller = Authlogic::ControllerAdapters::RailsAdapter.new(self)
  # line above was required by line below, but honestly I don't know why
  UserSession.new({email: 'my.email@gmail.com', password: 'aaaabbbb', password_confirmation: 'aaaabbbb'})

  get edit_service_url(@service)
  assert_response :success
end
```

Test fails and appears like I'm still not logged in. I wanted to ensure that my session wasn't created, so I added simple `puts` line:

```
test "should get edit" do
  Authlogic::Session::Base.controller = Authlogic::ControllerAdapters::RailsAdapter.new(self)
  UserSession.new({email: 'my.email@gmail.com', password: 'aaaabbbb', password_confirmation: 'aaaabbbb'})

  puts UserSession.find

  get edit_service_url(@service)
  assert_response :success
end
```

But after adding it I got this error, which is completely incomprehensible for me:

> Error: ServicesControllerTest#test_should_get_edit: NoMethodError:
>   undefined method 'params' for # /home/karol/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/testing/assertions/routing.rb:175:in
>   'method_missing'
>   /home/karol/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/testing/integration.rb:491:in
>   'method_missing'
>   /home/karol/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/authlogic-3.6.1/lib/authlogic/controller_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:30:in
>   'params'
>   /home/karol/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/authlogic-3.6.1/lib/authlogic/session/params.rb:111:in
>   'params_credentials'
>   /home/karol/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/authlogic-3.6.1/lib/authlogic/session/params.rb:86:in
>   'params_enabled?'
>   /home/karol/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/authlogic-3.6.1/lib/authlogic/session/params.rb:80:in
>   'persist_by_params'
>   /home/karol/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:382:in
>   'block in make_lambda'
>   /home/karol/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in
>   'block (2 levels) in halting'
>   /home/karol/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/authlogic-3.6.1/lib/authlogic/session/callbacks.rb:68:in
>   'block in included'
>   /home/karol/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:170:in
>   'block in halting'
>   /home/karol/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:454:in
>   'block in call'
>   /home/karol/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:454:in
>   'each'
>   /home/karol/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:454:in
>   'call'
>   /home/karol/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in
>   '__run_callbacks__'
>   /home/karol/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in
>   '_run_persist_callbacks'
>   /home/karol/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in
>   'run_callbacks'
>   /home/karol/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/authlogic-3.6.1/lib/authlogic/session/callbacks.rb:93:in
>   'persist'
>   /home/karol/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/authlogic-3.6.1/lib/authlogic/session/persistence.rb:56:in
>   'persisting?'
>   /home/karol/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/authlogic-3.6.1/lib/authlogic/session/persistence.rb:39:in
>   'find'
>   /home/karol/GitProjects/spotfinder/test/controllers/services_controller_test.rb:52:in
>   'block in '

What is it caused by and how can I write my test properly?

**EDIT:**

The code I'm testing:

```
class ServicesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authorise_for_service_id, only: [:edit]

  # ...

  def edit
  end

  # ...

  private:

  # ...

    def authorise_for_service_id
      if !is_user_id_current?(Service.find(params[:id]).user_id)
        redirect_to service_path(params[:id]), notice: 'Cannot perform your action: access denied.'
      end
    end
end

module ApplicationHelper

  # ...

  def is_user_id_current?(user_id)
    return current_user && current_user.id == user_id
  end
  def current_user
    return @current_user if defined?(@current_user)
    @current_user = current_user_session && current_user_session.user
  end
  def current_user_session
    return @current_user_session if defined?(@current_user_session)
    @current_user_session = UserSession.find
  end

  # ...

end

class UserSessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user_session = UserSession.new
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
    end
  end

  # POST /user_sessions
  def create
    @user_session = UserSession.new(user_session_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user_session.save
        format.html { redirect_to session[:return_to] || root_url, :notice => 'Login Successful!' }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /user_sessions/1
  def destroy
    @user_session = UserSession.find
    @user_session.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to session[:return_to] || root_url, :notice => 'Goodbye!' }
    end
  end

private
  def user_session_params
    params.require(:user_session).permit(:email, :password)
  end
end
```

Comment: Can we see the code you're actually trying to test?

Comment: @Andrei - of course, here you go